# unable to access youtube favorites on iPad1 since Youtube changed their API in April 2015

Tags: ios, ipad, youtube

My 3 years-old has been using my old iPad1 to watch videos on YouTube and 'saved' them in the 'favorites' section of the legacy youtube apps (icon is an old TV Set, not the new white arrow on a red background icon).
After some readings it appears that:
1- youtube does not support anymore this legacy youtube app since they use a new API since Apr.2015
2- when I try to get the new youTube App from the App Store, I'm being prompted to upgrade to iOS7 first
3- when I looked at upgrading an iPad1 with iOS7, most articles say that it is not possible (iOS7 hardware requirement not supported by iPad1)
I'm only trying to get back the list of favorites (i.e. video links) which seems to be still there in the YouTube apps...
If anyone is facing the same situation, happy to share thoughts and hopefully solutions!
Many thanks in advance,
David

Answer (score 1):

If you attempt to install the YouTube app on your device, you will be prompted to install the latest version that's still compatible with your device.

[You can read about this feature on Apple's support site.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201377)

[image: Screenshot of the prompt when installing YouTube on an original iPad]
[image: Screenshot of the iPad's About screen with some info censored]